# How to get the login username in Windows Admin Center's custom extension

Tags: wac

Windows Admin Center Settings shows Signed in account name. Can we retrieve that account name via AppContextService? or is there anyway to get the login username within the Windows Admin Center's custom extension?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This might also be a better question for another Stack Exchange Forum: ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an extention that shows you shows Signed in account name via AppContextService, but you might consider building your own tool extension.
Here is where you can start
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/extend/prepare-development-environment